# Скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую в SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Хочу сделать обновление БД у пользователей приложения т.к. в БД были добавлены новые записи (т.е. из новой версии БД скопировать в БД пользователей только те записи, которых у них нет.). БД содержит одну таблицу table1 с полями: _id (autoincrement), col1 (текстовое), col2 (текстовое) type (integer), favorites (integer).

Но не понимаю как это можно реализовать. Кто направит на путь истинный?

ВОТ выкладываю код из двух классов

```
public class Contract {
    private Contract() {
    };

    public static final class Entry implements BaseColumns {
        public final static String TABLE_NAME = "table1";

        public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public final static String COLUMN_WORD = "col1";
        public final static String COLUMN_TRANSLATION = "col2";
        public final static String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
        public final static String COLUMN_FAVORITES = "favorites";
    }
}
```

Второй класс

```
public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //Пусть к БД
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/ru.test.dbtest/databases/";
    //Имя файла базы данных
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbase.db";
    //Версия базы данных. При изменении схемы увеличить на единицу
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    //Объектная переменная типа SQLiteDatabase
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    //Конструктор
    //Третий параметр null в суперклассе используется для работы с курсорами. Сейчас их не используем, поэтому оставим в покое.
    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //ничего не делать - база уже есть
        }else{
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Проверяет, существует ли уже эта база, чтобы не копировать каждый раз при запуске приложения
     * @return true если существует, false если не существует
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e){
            //база еще не существует
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Копирует базу из папки assets заместо созданной локальной БД
     * Выполняется путем копирования потока байтов.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //закрываем потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //открываем БД
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            String query = "SELECT * from " + Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME;
            Cursor cr = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (newVersion == 2) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table2 (_id INTEGER, col1 TEXT NOT NULL, col2 TEXT NOT NULL, type INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                        "favorites INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (_id, col1, col2, type, favorites))");

                while (cr.moveToNext()) {
                    int idxCol1 = cr.getColumnIndex("col1");
                    int idxCol2 = cr.getColumnIndex("col2");
                    int idxID = cr.getColumnIndex("_id");
                    int idxType = cr.getColumnIndex("type");
                    int idxFavorites = cr.getColumnIndex("favorites");

                    String strCol1 = cr.getString(idxCol1);
                    String strCol2 = cr.getString(idxCol2);
                    String strID = cr.getString(idxID);
                    String strType = cr.getString(idxType);
                    String strFavorites = cr.getString(idxFavorites);

                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("col1", strCol1);
                    cv.put("col2", strCol2);
                    cv.put("_id", strID);
                    cv.put("type", strType);
                    cv.put("favorites", strFavorites);

                    long newRowId = db.insert("table2", null, cv);
                }
                db.execSQL("drop table table1");
                db.execSQL("alter table table2 rename to table1");

            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

БД закидывается в папку assets, т.е. заменяется файл db и приложение заново собирается в apk

Answer (score 2):

Нужно реализовать миграцию БД, подробно об этом можно почитать [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/79-urok-39-onupgrade-obnovljaem-bd-v-sqlite.html) . То есть например при обновлении базы с версии 1 на 2 будет выполнен ваш скрипт, который выполняет insert новых строк в таблицу table1. Для игнорирования уже существующих значений можно использовать функцию

```
mDb.insertWithOnConflict(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

(вместо той что в примере по ссылке)

```
db.insert("people", null, cv);
```

Comment: А можно чуть подробней как я могу из новой БД вытащить записи, которых нет в БД пользователей? Или мне нужно как в том примере для каждого столбца вытащить все записи в отдельные массивы и через ContentValues и метод insertWithOnConflict вставить их в БД?

Comment: Сделал так. в методе onUpgrade в курсор выбрал все записи и из для каждой колонки данные записал в отдельные коллекции. Затем через ContentValues положил это все в соответствующие столбцы и с помощью insertWithOnConflict вставил в таблицу. Походу я взял данные из таблицы и тупо обратно туда положил))) Подскажите как правильнее?

Comment: как выглядит новая БД? её данные это набор строк для table1? Если да то иможно использовать запросы в чистом виде, например REPLACE INTO table1 VALUES (1, '123', '12345', 1, 1);

Comment: Новая БД выглядит точно также, только там записей больше. Просто пользователи могут на своих устройствах добавлять новые записи в свои БД, редактировать их не трогая хочется в их БД добавить новые записи. Допустим я скачал приложение и в нем таблица table1 в которой 10 записей. В Новую версию БД я добавил еще 10 записей. Не трогая 10 тех записей как я могу добавить в БД юзеров новые 10 записей? 10 конечно к примеру. записей может быть и 10 тысяч.

Comment: текущая структура немного проблематична, так как видимо не предполагает защиту от дубликатов, только автоинкремент. Мое новое  предложение - в onUpdate создать новую таблицу с новыми данными, где остальные поля помимо айди - будут вторичными ключами. В новую таблицу (table2, с ключами которая) уже добавлять данные юзера. Тогда сработает проверка на дубликаты. Под конец переименовать таблицу в table1, перед этим удалив ту оригинальную.

Comment: А можно в виде простого кода это представить? Я изначально думал использовать вторую таблицу, даже начал создавал, но потом не знал как дальше в коде это сделать, поэтому оставил.

Comment: запросы будут выглядеть примерно так:    https://paste2.org/5fxhyzG9 (здесь проблемы с форматированием)

Comment: Сделал так, но не сработало. Где ошибки у меня?

Comment: Моя проблема в том, что я не знаю как вытащить данные из новой версии БД. Мой код обращается кажется к старой версии БД. Подскажите как из новой БД брать инфу

Comment: Покажите текущий код. В каком виде поставляется новая бд? Хорошо бы если это sql скрипт для одной таблицы

Comment: в описание вопроса добавил коды и инфо о бд

Comment: попробуй так - https://paste2.org/9F0yDdKs . То есть там читаем новые значения из новой базы и пишем их в старую.

Comment: Тупо вставил ваш код, поменял версию БД, но не сработало. Ошибок нет, но новые данные не появились в БД

Comment: В этом куске SQLiteDatabase assetDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); разве обращение идет не к той же БД что у пользователя стоит?

Comment: да действительно, там по идее должна открываться база которая у вас в assets, я неправильно понял путь

Comment: А как открыть БД из assets?

Comment: напрямую никак. нужно сделать аналог copydatabase() только который пишет не в текущую базу а с другим именем по тому же пути (outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME + "_temp";). Затем открыть по этому пути

Comment: Понял. Тогда можно получается БД из assets скопировать с новым названием, вытащить из нее данные, которых нет в БД юзера, записать в БД юзера и удалить тестовую БД

Comment: не создавая дополнительных таблиц с БД у юзера

Answer (score 1):

Помоему намного проще сделать средствами SQL без посредника в виде java. Если необходимо не все записи вставлять, то во втором запросе с INSERT можно добавить условие для SELECT

```
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table2 (_id INTEGER, col1 TEXT NOT NULL, col2 TEXT NOT NULL, type INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    "favorites INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (_id, col1, col2, type, favorites))");
           db.execSQL("insert into table2 (_id,col1,col2,type,favorites) select _id,col1,col2,type,favorites from table1");
           db.execSQL("drop table table1");
           db.execSQL("alter table table2 rename to table1");
```